# best backend services platforms

Tags: java, android, cordova, backend, mbaas

I am trying to build native app (ios, android) using cordova , ionic framework, html5. this native app talks to my REST service, which is implemented using java/j2ee, no sql db(like mongodb).based on the request, this REST service gets data from db or calls someother external remote REST service using a java REST Client object.
I would like to keep my REST service and the DB on cloud.
I have started working on html, css and js code using ionic, angularjs on my local webstorm IDE on my mac. 
I intend to use sms, email, maps in my app.

My question is , what are the best cloud based backend as service offerings out there..
I have looked at appery.io but it does not execute java code, we can have custom javascript code on the server.do i rewrite my server logic into javascript code ?
is heroku of anyhelp in my case ?

Can anybody please guide me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [backendless](http://backendless.com), it supports custom server code in Java. There is also a free plan that is more than enough to build a solid app.

Comment: Thank you.I will signup for free plan and check it out if it fits my req.